# Will my AWS usage cost me anything?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I was exploring AWS Cloudwatch. It was first time that I tried anything on AWS. I ensured that I will turn off all instances and stacks:

- **No stacks:**
  [image]
- **No instances**
  [image]

But my AWS Billing Dashboard says this:

[image]

Will I need to pay anything, considering that above billing amount is forecast, I have turned off all instances and stacks and I may not have exceeded my free tier (I have used AWS first time)?

**Update**

Another screenshot:

[image]

So I have following precise questions:

**Q.** Will this cost increase further? That is, do I have to stop all the services correctly (as shown in earlier pics) to not increase the cost further, or is there something that I missed?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will need to pay based on what you're showing.  If you have a billing question, you can create a support case in the AWS Console.

Will the cost increase depends on if you shut off or deleted services.  If you shut everything off you could still get charged for EBS volume storage.  If you deleted the EC2 instance(s) and deleted any storage (S3/EBS/Glacier) you should not see any additional charges.

I have been hit with surprise bills in the past by not deleting EBS volumes when I delete an instance, or forgetting about objects in S3.

If you go to **Billing Dashboard** and click on **Bills** on the left side of the page you will see an option for **Details**.  You can see why you're getting charged their.

[image]

Some important things to know about the AWS Free Tier:

1. The 12-months Free starts from the day you create the account.
2. It's per Organization, if your account is linked to an Organization it will depend when the Org was created and if the free-tier limits have been reached because of other accounts in that Org.
3. It's per account and not per region.
4. There are some services that are always free (until you hit a usage level)

**References**
[AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free) 
[AWS How Do I Check If I've Exceeded Free Tier](https://youtu.be/_CWKK0sypkE)

Comment: ok I got it, it says $1.62. But will it increase further, that is whether I have stopped all services correctly?

Comment: @anir that depends on the service(s) that created the charge.  If it still says $1.62 today then I would say you're safe that it's not going to go up.  But if it's a service like S3 or EBS you could get the same charge next month.